# Do we always assume principal values converge?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis

Consider this simple textbook real integral

$$I = p.v.   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^2 + 4} dx  = \lim_{\rho \to \infty} \int_{-\rho}^{\rho} \frac{\cos x}{x^2 + 4} dx$$

Now in many books it can be split as such

$$I = p.v. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{2(x^2 + 4)} dx +  p.v. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ix}}{2(x^2 + 4)} dx \quad (*)$$

where we are integrating over the real line so its imaginary component $y = 0$ and so $x$ is completely real. Then Jordan's lemma can be applied to show the circular part tends to $0$.

But in order to write $(*)$, don't we have to assume $p.v. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{2(x^2 + 4)} dx$ has to exist first? Otherwise how do we justify splitting the original integral

$$p.v. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2(x^2 + 4)} dx$$

==========

Consider $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2} dx = -\pi/2.$$ This can be found via $Re \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}-1 }{x^2} dx$. But this is only true $\iff$

$$\lim_{\rho \to \infty}\int_{-\rho}^{\rho} \frac{e^{ix}-1 }{x^2} dx = \lim_{\rho \to \infty}\int_{-\rho}^{\rho} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2} dx + i\lim_{\rho \to \infty}\int_{-\rho}^{\rho} \frac{\sin x}{x^2} dx$$

But in all the answers I am reading from the manual, they never bothered to show one part ($i\lim_{\rho \to \infty}\int_{-\rho}^{\rho} \frac{\sin x}{x^2} dx$) converges. They just assume either the imaginary/real part converges and take the real/imaginary part.

And I threw [$i\lim_{\rho \to \infty}\int_{-\rho}^{\rho} \frac{\sin x}{x^2} dx$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C-infinity%2Cinfinity%7D%5D) into Mathematica and it gives no value.

Now I know the original integral converges because it is a textbook problem, but there is something fundamentally wrong in immediately assuming we can split the integral like that.

Comment: The integrand is summable, why would you need the principal value here?

Comment: Because that isn't related to my question. I am not interested in the value.

Comment: Because $x \mapsto {1 \over x^2+4}$ is integrable and $\sin, \cos, x \mapsto e^{ix}$ are all bounded by one.

Comment: It is a bit odd to have principal value in the question title and then say it is not related to your question.

Comment: I guess that part was left out in the explanation. I used Saff's book for this example

Comment: Perhaps they are using Riemann integration. I guess I could call it improper rather than the principal value. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value for example.

Comment: To answer your question, yes you would have to justify the existence of the integral, but it is straightforward here so they probably didn't feel the need to elaborate.

Comment: http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~kryakin/w9.pdf actually I just found another example of this on page 19/26. Its usually the first example that serves before Jordan's lemma.

Comment: Yes, but notice on p.21 that the denominator has a singularity at $x=0$. The integrals above do not. The pv. is superfluous.

Comment: Look I don't come up with the questions, it is in the textbook.

Comment: Look, if you are referring to the integral on p.19, there is no mention of pv., nor is there any need to. The term ${ 1 \over 1+x^2}$ is absolutely integrable over the real line. Since all of $\cos x,\sin x, e^{ix}$ are bounded it follows that all the integrals above exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we always assume principal values converge?

No.

> But in order to write $(*)$, don't we have to assume $p.v. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{2(x^2 + 4)} dx$ has to exist first?

Yes.  However, that's what you should show in the next steps.  In essence, we show the justification for being able to split the sum at the same time we evaluate the principal values of the summands.  If you want it to follow more logically, you could reverse the order in your solution.

Then, paraphrased from the comments, we have:

> Why are we considering the principal value integral?

Typically, the solution method as a contour integral only proves that the principal value integral exists, not the more general improper integral.  If we are able to show that the improper integral itself exists, then evaluating the principal value integral allows us to conclude the full improper integral has the same value.

---

**In reference to your latest example:**

The short answer is that $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ is an odd function with one singularity at $x=0$, so $$\text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\,dx = 0$$ does exist.

In the theory, we *always* have that $z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ converges to $a+bi$ ($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$) if and only if $\Re(z_n), \Im(z_n) \in \mathbb{R}$ each converge to $a$ and $b$ respectively.

In your latest example, the solution would have shown that $$\text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx$$ exists and equals $-\pi$ (I haven't checked whether this is the right value, but it sounds plausible).  As a result of the above theorem we may conclude that both the following principal value integrals converge with the following values:
$$\text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2}\,dx = -\pi \\ \text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\,dx = 0$$
To rephrase my answer to the second highlighted question above for the present context, **the method used in the solution to evaluate the one complex-valued integral proves both the imaginary and real parts converge with the appropriate values.**

As for why your Mathematica input gave no output for the limit
$$\lim_{\rho\to\infty} \int_{-\rho}^\rho \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\,dx$$
it's because this integral doesn't exist.  This, however, isn't a problem since this isn't how the principal value integral is evaluated.  Specifically, in this case,
$$\text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\,dx = \lim_{\rho\to\infty \\ \epsilon\to 0^+} \left(\int_{-\rho}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\sin x}{x^2}\,dx + \int_\epsilon^\rho \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\,dx\right)$$

Comment: "However, that's what you should show in the next steps. In essence, we show the justification for being able to split the sum at the same time we evaluate the principal values of the summands. If you want it to follow more logically, you could reverse the order in your solution" 

This doesn't line up since many integral in textbooks excerises immediately assume one part converges. For example taking th real/imaginary part to show the cosine/sine part of the integral

Comment: @Hawk Without an example to show me what you mean, you leave me guessing on how to respond.  It really sounds like you're arguing against $$z_n \in \mathbb{C} \text{ converges } \iff \Re{z_n}, \Im{z_n} \in \mathbb{R} \text{ both converge}$$
but this is known as a basic theorem and has very little to do with splitting $$z_n = w_{1,n} + w_{2,n}$$
into two complex sequences.

Comment: I'll write one tomorrow. But it more or less has to do with what you wrote.

Comment: Added detail in OP. too long

Comment: @Hawk See the update to my answer.

Comment: OKay I think there is a miscommunication. The only reason you know $ \text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\,dx = 0$ is because we computed it. But if you were computing $\text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx$ blindly and take the real/imaginary part, we are assuming (1)$ \text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx$ already converges and (2) the Imaginary and real part converges, hence we pass the limit and use the addition law for infinite limits.

Comment: No.  I _personally_ know that because I computed it, but I didn't need to if I had evaluated the complex-valued principal value integral.  That is, **all I need to know** is that $$\text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx$$ exists and equals $-\pi.$  My point is that this is what ought to be shown in the solution.

Comment: I don't think we are understanding each other. The only way you could have computed $\text{p.v.}\!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx$ is to use the Residue theorem and use the limit law of addition. But the addition law does not hold if the imaginary/real part don't converge. If you don't show this, you can't use that method. This is like chicken and the egg.

Comment: And my point is that in many of these excerises, you are just to accept the convergence on the real/imaginary part.

Comment: And my point is that you are incorrect that we are using the "limit law of addition".  We are using, as I mentioned several times, that $z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ converges if and only if the real and imaginary parts converge.  In the solution, we prove that the complex-valued integral converges.  Therefore the real part of the integral and the imaginary part of the integral converges for free.